# Changing the src of an img using (treeCut.src = "images/treeCut.png";)

Tags: javascript, html

My idea is to change the image from a full tree to a cut tree and back to a full tree. My problem is when I change it to the picture of the cut tree the image doesn't show, but when it switches back the image of the full tree works fine. Here's the script the pertains to the problem:

```
var treeCut;

switch(randomEvent){
        case 1:
         //add a log
         document.getElementById("treeActive").innerHTML = "inActive1";
         treeSpawn=setTimeout(spawnTree,5000);
                 //below is the piece i'm having issues with
         treeCut = document.getElementById("treeButton");
         treeCut.src = function() {
             treeCut.src = "images/treeCut.png";
         } 
        break;

//not showing the full switch just the part that is being exicuted.

function spawnTree(){
    document.getElementById("treeActive").innerHTML = "Active";
    count = 0;
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "chop " + count;
    clearInterval(treeSpawn);
        //brings the tree back to original image
    treeCut.src = "images/tree.png";
}
```

Is there a problem because the second image needs to have a tag of its own? I have checked, double checked, and triple checked that the image is in the correct place and correctly named.

Comment: As you said that you have checked that the image is placed in the proper root with proper name may be the button id you are using is not the correct one. And you could use an alert inside the function to check whether the function is even getting compiled or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could have just set the `src` of image directly, like, change:

```
treeCut.src = function() {
    treeCut.src = "images/treeCut.png";
}
```

to

```
treeCut.src = "images/treeCut.png";
```

Comment: you're welcome.. :) if that solved your problem you could mark it as Accepted Answer.. :)